# differentiable sets of an arbitrary function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary function. I have proved that the set $E$ of points where $f$ is continuous is a Borel set.

For $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p,q,r\in \mathbb{Q}$, let 
\begin{equation}
H(k,p,q,r)=\{x\in E\cap (q,r): |f(y)-f(x)-p(y-x)|\leq 2^{-k}|y-x| \text{for all   }y\in(q,r)\}.
\end{equation}
Then I have proved
\begin{equation}
\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup _{p,q,r\in\mathbb{Q}}H(k,p,q,r)=\{x:f \text{ is differentiable at }x \}.
\end{equation}
To prove the above set $\{x:f \text{ is differentiable at }x \}$ to be a Borel set, I need to prove $H(k,p,q,r)$ is a Borel set. How to do this?